# How to prove that $\det(A)\geq 1$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Given $A \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ with $A+A^t=2I_n$ prove that $\det(A)\geq 1$.

This is what I tried to do:

$$A+A^t-2I_n=0  \Rightarrow \det(A+A^t-2I_n)=0$$

and then I considered $f:\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ with $f(x)= \det(A+A^t+xI_n)$.

It is known that  $f(x)=x^2+\mathrm{Tr}(A+A^t)x+ \det(A+A^t)$.

So this means $f(-2)=0$ but I don't know what to do next..
Thanks in advance!

Comment: $A-I=I-A^t$, so $A-I$ is skew-symmetric....

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. Thank you for posting not only the question, but also your thoughts. As to your formula for $f$: In general $f$ will be an $n$-th degree polynomial, not a quadratic function.